# How can I make sure that Nginx serves plaintext files as a download, instead of inline?

Tags: nginx, mime-type

I have Rails application (Redmine) which works with Nginx.  If I am clicking on any attachment my browser (firefox, ie, chrome) ask me to download file.  But if I am clicking on txt-type attachment my browser open this file in the browser.

As I understand it is task of Nginx to decide - open file in the browser or to download it.  How can I setup it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default type for txt extension is text/plain. This behavior is described in mime.types file. Use http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type or http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types to override it (maybe set to application/octet-stream).

Answer (score 22):

Changing the `Content-Type` of `.txt` files may work, but it's a somewhat risky way to solve this problem, because you can't guarantee 100% that the user's browser will respond how you expect. And furthermore, it's misleading to label a `.txt` file as a binary file.

Instead, I suggest using the standard way to force a browser to download rather than display the file, which is to use the `Content-Disposition` header with a value of `attachment` ([RFC 2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt), see also [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)).

For example, this nginx `location` block will send down such a header with `.txt` files under the `/downloads/` URI and thus they will be forced to download:

```
location ~ ^/downloads/.*\.txt$ {
  add_header Content-Disposition "attachment";
}
```

So you could add other appropriate matching, etc, appropriate to your configuration.

Comment: It seems to be the best solution.

Comment: But `Content-Disposition` hack in chromium browser can start saying bad words into console and even stop downloading any files from page. It says thinhgs (with yellow triangles) like: `"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png:"`

Answer (score 4):

You need to extract location for downloadable file and set their content-type as `application/octet-stream`.

We have following location on our service for downloadable promomaterial (which includes pdfs, images and some docs, but I'm sure it will work with txt files as well):

```
location /promomaterial/download/ {
         add_header Content-Type application/octet-stream;
}
```

Every browser we've tried downloads all files from this location instead of trying to display them.

Comment: Using "add_header" it's absolutely wrong, use "default_type" instead:  location /smth/ {
                default_type application/octet-stream;;
        }

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin Why is default_type better than add_header?

Comment: @user193661 Because "add_header" it's litterally adds new header "Content-Type", so in response you can get two "Content-Type" headers   what can lead to strange behaviour of HTTP clients. "default_type" is set(overwrite) single "Content-Type" header in response.